# Given $\mathbf{A}$ stable (all negative eigenvalues), produce a bound on $\|\mathbf{B}\|$ such that...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Given a system:

$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\left(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}\right)\mathbf{x}$

Can you bound $\|\mathbf{B}\|$ s.t. the origin of $\mathbf{x}$ is exponentially stable using a Lyapunov function?

Without the Lyapunov function approach, I was able to derive that:

$\|\mathbf{B}\|_{2} < \lambda_{min}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)$

Where $\lambda_{min}$ is the minimum eigenvalue.